# Can't modify permissions for a file I just created via OAuth in Google Drive API

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api

I have a web app that allows users to sign in via oAuth, which grants them the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` scope, and then they can create and edit text files via `files.create` and `files.update`. This all works fine in Node.js using the `googleapis` NPM module.

However, I also allow other users to view and edit those files via my app if they are accessed via the appropriate link. To do this, as soon as the file is created, I also immediately create a permission for that file as in the code below.

This works fine 95% of the time, but occasionally, I have a user get an error which shows up as a 403 error from Google, with the message "the user does not have sufficient permissions for this file." The file is created just fine, as he can verify by manually opening the folder in Google Drive, but the app errors out at the "drive.permissions.create" step, and afterward, that same file cannot be opened or edited by him via the app with the same error.

What in the world is going on? Why does my user not have permissions for his own file he just created half a second ago via OAuth, and why does it work for most everyone else? Regenerating the access/refresh tokens does not help him either. I'm so confused.

```
const drive = google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth: Oauth }); //Oauth credentials generated at login

const media = {
    mimeType : 'text/plain',
    body     : newfile.text
};

const fileMetadata = {
    'name'        : `${newfile.title}.txt`,
    'description' : `${newfile.description}`,
    'parents'     : [folderId],
    'properties'  : {
        'title'   : newfile.title,
    }
};

const obj = await drive.files.create({
    resource : fileMetadata,
    media    : media
})
.catch((err)=>{
    console.error(err);
    return res.status(500).send('Error while creating new file');
});

if(!obj) return;

await drive.permissions.create({
    resource : { type : 'anyone',
                 role : 'writer' },
    fileId : obj.data.id,
    fields : 'id',
})
.catch((err)=>{
    console.error(err);
    return res.status(500).send('Error updating permissions');
});
```

Comment: This only happens to one user and even though the error is shown, the file is properly created? Does it also happen if the user just uses the permissions create alone? To avoid the permissions create to be executed before the file is completely created.

Comment: It happens to a handful of people (20+ people have reported this to me, I suspect it's actually more). No error occurs on `drive.files.create()`. That part is fine. The error occurs on the `drive.permissions.create()` step, which can only occur after waiting for the file to be created and returned as `obj`, which you can see in the example code I posted. After the file is created, the user can no longer get, update, or add permissions to that file, even though it plainly exists in their drive folder and they can see it being added, with a 403 "not enough permissions for this file" error.

Comment: On the web UI, do the user have permissions to modify the file? Or the user gets the same error than on the permissions modification from the script?

Comment: After they first create the file, any further interaction through my app (get, update, create permissions, delete) gives the 403 "not enough permissions for this file" error. They can view and edit the file fine by opening the file in Google Drive.

Comment: Have you checked with those users or if you can reproduce it with a test account, if they can update / create the permissions with the [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/update) for files permissions?